# How to get SolidColorbrush/Brush from "ANY" Decimal value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a converter for translate decimal color value to SolidColorBrush, the values are stored in the database.

I'm doing the conversión in two steps.

1. Transalte decimal to Hexadecimal
2. Translate Hexadecimal to SolidColorBrush

Here is the code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        string HexVal = string.Format("#{0}", (Int32.Parse(value.ToString())).ToString("X"));
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(HexVal));
    }
    catch (Exception ex )
    {
       . . . .
    }
}
```

Now My problema is some valuesworks pretty well such as 7897995,255 and others. But when try somes like black (0) it throw an exception. Something like

**System.FormatException: Symbol (token) is not valid.
   at MS.Internal.Parsers.ParseColor(String color, IFormatProvider formatProvider, ITypeDescriptorContext context)
   at System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(String value)**

I tryed to:

```
(SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(HexVal));
```

and

```
(Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(HexVal))
```

Now I have two questions:

1. If #FFFF00 is a valid color, why can't conver it to SolidColorbrush?
2. There is a better way to perform this  conversión?

Comment: A 32-bit integer would store ARGB values in its 4 bytes, but how exactly is a decimal used to encode a color value? And is it really type `decimal` or probably a floating point value?

Comment: Allready a decimal value. It is stored at database as  Black = 0 , light blue = 12903679 and so on... Light Blue Works with my converter, but , black doesn´t

Comment: So without alpha value, and the fractional part of the decimal is ignored?

Comment: Yes, those colors are taken from Access application.

Comment: All I have stored in the database is that value, a decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably directly convert the value to `int`, than get the RGB bytes from the `int` and create a `Color` value from those bytes:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var decimalValue = (decimal)value;
    var intValue = (int)decimalValue;
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
    var color = Color.FromRgb(bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
    return new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
```

---

FYI, the problem in your approach was the string format `"#{0}"`, which e.g. creates `#0` instead of `#000000` for black.